# sql server management studio shortcut to delete a row

Tags: row, ssms, shortcut

Is there a shortcut in Management Studio 2012 to delete the row where the cursor is.
Except <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, because this has the side effect on your text saved before with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is deleted after the shortcut.
Is should work like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Eclipse.

Comment: For all your SSMS keyboard shortcut needs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> do the deleting job (by cutting and placing to buffer) entire line where the cursor are.
 Which can be a useful alternative to setting "delete" shortcut manually.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking for a way to do this WITHOUT cutting the line to the clipboard, the command you want is called `Edit.LineDelete`. You can get to it by going to `Tools --> Options --> Environment --> Keyboard --> Keyboard` and searching for the command in the text box.

You may also need to make sure that the key combination you're assigning it to isn't already being used by anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no shortcut in SQL Server Management Studio to delete a row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change short cut key from `Tools` **-** `Options` and then `Keyboard`.

See in below image.

[image]

Instead of, `Shift  + Del` you can assign any, you want to set. (Except default keys)